# Reading Value from property file at runtime

Tags: java, properties, cassandra, runtime, properties-file

I have a following function :

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

    String term = input.getString(0);
    int year = input.getInteger(1);
    int month = input.getInteger(2);
    int day = input.getInteger(3);
    int hour = input.getInteger(4);
    int dayofyear = input.getInteger(5);
    int weekofyear = input.getInteger(6);
    int productcount = input.getInteger(7);

    /*
     * Inserting Values In Cassandra
     */

    String insertUpdateTable = "UPDATE TopQuery SET count = count + 1 "
            + "where term = \'" + term + "\' AND year = " + year
            + " AND month = " + month + " AND day = " + day
            + " AND hour = " + hour + " AND dayofyear = " + dayofyear
            + " AND weekofyear = " + weekofyear + " AND productcount = "
            + productcount + ";";

    session.executeAsync(insertUpdateTable);

}
```

Here i'll be getting all the values like `term` , `year` , `month` , `day` , `hour` , `dayofyear` , `weekofyear`  and `productcount` at runtime and will insert it into Cassandra DB.

Since, this String is constant and doesn't change I want to separate it out and put it into properties file.

I have already put the table structure into properties file and fetching it from there.So that, In future if i need to change the table structure I don't have to edit the code , rather I can simply edit the properties file.

But,How to store the `insertUpdateTable` in properties file so that it reads the data at runtime and updates the DB  ?

Comment: You might want to look at [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Additionally, there are structural changes that will force the code to be changed. Think about adding a column ...

Comment: `PreparedStatement : An object that represents a precompiled SQL statement. ` Does it only work  for SQL or for other dbs ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose : Cassandra also supports `PreparedStatement` . Exactly the thing i was looking for.Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

To read a property file you can use the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

> The Properties class represents a persistent set of properties. The
>   Properties can be saved to a stream or loaded from a stream. Each key
>   and its corresponding value in the property list is a string.

But I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put SQL (or other code) into a property file. There's no difference in editing a java or a property file to change the SQL. After all it's a code change which requires testing and deployment. In every non trivial project you want to automate this steps anyway (ant, maven, ...).

Answer (score 0):

in xyz.properties put value like this

query = *************

Now Try this

```
getProperties(){
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                String propFileName = "xyz.properties";

                inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

                prop.load(inputStream);
                String query= prop.getProperty("query");
              }
```